# Issue with react component loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I decided to learn react this weekend and things have been going well in JSFiddle, however i decided to add a 4th component (var gooBye...) and now the view is empty. Any thoughts on what could be causing this? No errors popping up
[JSFiddle React components](http://jsfiddle.net/kgee/r4p96jdg/4/)

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});

var testButton = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
    return <button name="button">Click</button>; 
  }
});
 
 var goodBye = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
    return <div>GoodBye</div>;
  }
});


React.render(
 <Hello name="People" />, 
 document.getElementById('myClass');
);
    
ReactDOM.render(
  testButton(),
  document.getElementById('test2');
);
    
React.render(
   <goodBye />,
   document.getElementById('test3');
);   
    
<div id="myClass">
   </div>
 <div id="test1">
 </div>
 <div id="test2">
  </div>
  <div id="test3">  
  </div>
 <script type="text/jsx">
    ReactDOM.render(
     <h1>Test component in html body</h1>,
      document.getElementById('test');
    );
 </script>


</body>
```

Comment: Pardon the "ReactDOM" I was trying to troubleshooting

Comment: you should use ReactDOM only, react.render is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple syntax errors, I can see them the second I open your jsfiddle console:

You need to use `ReactDOM.render`. `react.render` is deprecated
You cant have that last semi colon in your parenthesis: `(<example>, asdfasdf;)` should be `(<example>, asdfasdf)`

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <TestButton />,
  document.getElementById('test2') // no semi-colon here!
);
```

You need to have capitals in front of your components.

```
var TestButton = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <button name="button">Click</button>; 
  }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle with one of your examples (the code above)...you're close just be very careful about the syntax.

[Fiddle React](https://jsfiddle.net/5ztcLvuL/1/)

Comment: thanks for the clarification on ReactDOM. I've capitalized components and removed the semicolons but I still cant get the components back up https://jsfiddle.net/kgee/r4p96jdg/6/

Comment: you can have one ReactDOM.render per page, you need to put all the components in one React element, we call these containers...

Answer (score -1):

Component names should start with capital letter, e.g. `GoodBye`.

When an element name in JSX starts with a small letter, React assumes it's a native HTML (or SVG...) element, for example a `<div>` or an `<input>`. When it starts with a capital letter, it assumes it's a React component, e.g. `<Hello>` or `<GoodBye>`.

```
var GoodBye = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>GoodBye</div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <GoodBye />,
    document.getElementById('test3')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I've adjusted the component name and still no dice.